# Embedded SWF File Wrong Size

Tags: html, flash, embed, swfobject

On my website, an SWF file I have embedded from a separate media server is incredibly small. I had no issues with this before, however, I use a template HTML which several pages draw info out of. I changed something on one of the pages and it altered the size of the SWF on another.

Here is the HTML code as found in Inspect Element for the SWF Holder and Embed:

```
<section id="D_F_GameSection"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="cp_flash" name="cp_flash" class="disney_land_clubpenguin_player" data="http://media.cphistory.pw/play/v2/client/club_penguin.swf?clientVersion=21639" width="100%" height="100%"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="flashvars"
```

Here is the code relating to it in the HTML template:

```
"flash_game_settings":{"recommendedSwfVersion":"12.0.0.44","minimumSwfVersion":"10.1","loadSwf":media + "play\/v2\/client\/club_penguin.swf?clientVersion=21639"
```

I tried adding "width" and "height" options into the template code, with the syntax seen in the inspect element code, but all that did was cause the webpage to not load the Embedded SWF at all.

How would I correct the size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure everything else on the page is formatted correctly, it may be offset in place and size due to that.